# mysql error 1072

Tags: mysql, sql

```
COMMIT WORK
;
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS Campaign_Database;
CREATE DATABASE Campaign_Database;
USE Campaign_Database;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CONTRIBUTOR
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CAMPAIGN
;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PLEDGE
;

CREATE TABLE CONTRIBUTOR
(   CONTRIBUTOR_ID VARCHAR(50) primary key,
    Address char(50) not null,
    City char(50) not null,
    State char(2) not null,
    Zip INTEGER(6) not null,
    Home_Phone char (15)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
;
CREATE TABLE CAMPAIGN
(   CAMPAIGN_ID VARCHAR(50)  primary key,
    Chair_First_Name char (50) not null,
    Chair_Last_Name char (50) not null,
    Launch_Date char (11) not null,
    End_Date char (11) not null,
    Fundraising_Goal INTEGER NOT NULL
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
;

CREATE table PLEDGE
(
    FOREIGN KEY (CONTRIBUTOR_ID) REFERENCES CONTRIBUTOR (CONTRIBUTOR_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CAMPAIGN_ID) REFERENCES CAMPAIGN (CAMPAIGN_ID),
    Date_Pledged char(11) not null primary key,
    Amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PAID char(1) not null
    CHECK (PAID in ('Y','N')),
    Payment_Date char(11)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
;

COMMIT WORK
;
```

This current is the mysql coding I am using for a finals assignment.
I have tried several methods but was not successful in creating the two foreign keys within the 'pledge' table.

I would be appreciated if I can at least know what went wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `CONTRIBUTOR_ID`, `CAMPAIGN_ID` fields in the `PLEDGE` table.

```
CREATE table PLEDGE
(
    CONTRIBUTOR_ID VARCHAR(50),
    CAMPAIGN_ID VARCHAR(50),
    FOREIGN KEY (CONTRIBUTOR_ID) REFERENCES CONTRIBUTOR (CONTRIBUTOR_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CAMPAIGN_ID) REFERENCES CAMPAIGN (CAMPAIGN_ID),
    Date_Pledged char(11) not null primary key,
    Amount INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PAID char(1) not null
    CHECK (PAID in ('Y','N')),
    Payment_Date char(11)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;
;
```

In this statement

```
FOREIGN KEY (CONTRIBUTOR_ID) REFERENCES CONTRIBUTOR (CONTRIBUTOR_ID),
```

The first `CONTRIBUTOR_ID` refers to the table where the contraint is defined and the second refers to the table where it is pointing to.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, when I add the CONTRIBUTOR_ID and CAMPAIGN_ID to the pledge table an error message pops up again. This time the error code is 1136 stating the value does not match the row one data.

Comment: @J_Chong: Check the fiddler http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/07670a , tables are created successfully. I think error 1136 arise while inserting values to the table if the supplied value not match the column count in the table.